# mysql server is not running, gives the error failed

Tags: mysql

mysql server is not running, gives the error failed

Earlier it was working, but when I killed the mysqld process by `kill -9 process_id`

Now when I try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

it gives error

```
Starting MySql database server: mysqld................failed!
```

Tried searching so many things, no solution. 
Any help or suggestions

Comment: Did you look at `mysql.err`?

Comment: @tadman - yes I already seen that, it's empty

Comment: Is there a stale `mysql.pid` type file anywhere? You need to find an error message of some sort. If you don't care about your data, trash the MySQL database directory and do another `mysql_install_db`.

Comment: @tadman `mysqld` folder is empty, there is no `mysqld.pid` or `mysqld.sock` file, not anywhere. tadman I care about my data

Comment: Then you should make an immediate backup of that data and try and restore it on another system before you wreck around with this system and possibly lose that data. Copying the contents of the `mysql` data directory is a sub-optimial backup strategy, using `mysqldump` or `innobackupex` is better, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @tadman - ok thank you so much for the advice, but can you tell me what may be the reason behind this?

Comment: Without an error of some sort it could be any of a hundred things. Out of disk space? MySQL libraries corrupted? Failed upgrade at the OS level? Cosmic rays?

Comment: Killing `mysql` with -9 is severe and there's no guarantees it will spin up properly afterwards. It's the equivalent of pulling the plug on the computer instead of shutting down properly. It might leave your InnoDB tables in a crashed state, though there's normally a note about this in the MySQL error log. Be *sure* you're looking at the correct log, you might have several of them for some reason.